# How to get a date out of this string Wed Dec 11 16:02:54 CET 2019

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am getting this date from backend. I need to compare this with same kind of date. I tried different posts but I am always getting as Invalid date or NAN

**String samples :   Wed Dec 11 16:02:54 CET 2019**

**String samples :   Wed Dec 11 14:43:24 CET 2019**

Comment: What is `CET` here?

Comment: central europe time

Comment: Do you have any control over the backend? It'd be preferable to get the dates in the form of timestamps or a more easily parsed format in the first place.

Comment: Thats my last choice.looking to fix in front end

Comment: That's doing things backwards and creating more work for yourself now and probably down the line. If you can make the backend send dates properly, do that instead.

Comment: Can you use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) here. Since there are fixed [timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations) only, that can be stored in array and extracted from the string. Then format your other date in that timezone and use moment functions for comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need both [moment](https://momentjs.com/) and [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) to parse timezones.

> **[String + Format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)**
>
> If you know the format of an input string, you can use that to parse a moment.
>
> `moment("12-25-1995", "MM-DD-YYYY");`

In your case, `moment('Wed Dec 11 16:02:54 CET 2019', 'ddd MMM DD HH:mm:ss Z YYYY')`